# Prove that $\exists x\in \mathbb{R}: x > 2 \land 10^x> x^{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

$$\exists  x\in \mathbb{R}: x > 2 \land 10^x> x^{10}$$

I tried:

$$x>2 \land 10^x>x^{10} = x > 2 \land 10^2>2^{10} = x > 2 \land 100 > 1024$$

Honestly I am not entirely sure of what the expression means. I think it means "There is an $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ that is greater than 2 so that $10^x > x^{10}$.

Is this correct? How do I prove this?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct. I don't quite understand the symbolic manipulation you did (and I don't think it's right). As for proving the statement: you could prove it by giving an example of a number $x$ that is greater than $2$ and such that $10^x > x^{10}$. What about $x=100$?

Comment: yes the backwards E looking symbol is 'there exists', so it reads 'there exists an x in R such that x > 2 AND 10^x > x^10. So you just need to show that an x exists that satisfies those conditions.

Comment: @Dan90 But how do I do that?

Comment: The sentence is literally that the is a real number, x, greater than 2 and 10^x > x^10.  So yes, your interpretation is correct. 10^2 < x^10.  10^10 = 10^10.  11^10 < 10^11.  I single example will prove it.

Comment: Not for "when is $x^a$ equal, greater, less than $a^x$ questions if $x = a$ you have $a^a = a^a$ of course.  So either $a^x - x^a$ is increasing, decreasing or plateauing.  If it's not plateauing then there will be x < a and an x > a where $a^x > x^a$ and $a^x < x^a$.  To see if $a^x - x^a$ is incr, decreasing, or plateauing take derivative $a^x*\ln a - a*x^{a-1}$.  At $x = a$ this is $a^a(\ln a - 1)$  So it's increasing if $a > e$ and $a^{x^+} > x^a$, decreasing if $a< e$ and $a^{x^-} > x^a$ and if $a = e$ we need to take second derivative to out if max or min.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one. Take $x=2^{10}$. We have 
$$10^x=10^{1024}=(10^4)^{256}>x^{256}>x^{10}.$$

Comment: I understand your solution,  but is there a more... "mathematical" way of solving this? I mean, what is the correct value is big? Guessing the number won't work then... This can be solved using the graphs, but I was looking for a more analytical solution

Comment: It is a ‘mathematical way’, as you say. The initial idea was to iterate from $x=2$ to $x=10^2$. If it wouldn't have been enough, I would have tried $x=10^{10^2}$. Of course this does not yields the first $x$ for which the inequality is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log x$ denote $\log_{10}x$. Note that 
$$
10^x>x^{10}\ \Leftrightarrow\ 
\log(10^x)>\log(x^{10})
\ \Leftrightarrow\ 
x\overbrace{\log10}^{=1}>10\log x
\ \Leftrightarrow\ 
\frac{x}{\log x}>10
$$
Taking $x=100$ yields $x>2$ and 
$$
\frac{x}{\log x}=\frac{100}{\log 100}=\frac{100}{2}=50>10
$$
as required.

Comment: Could you explain $\frac{x}{\log x}$?

Comment: of course. see my edited answer again (-:

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $10^{10}\ge10^{10}$, then $10^{10.00001}>10.00001^{10}$, as the exponential grows faster than the power.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Thought process:

$x=2;  10^2 = 100 < 2^{10} = 1024$

$x=3; 10^3 = 1000 < 3^{10} > 1024$ and this is getting nowhere.

But $x = 10; 10^{10} = 10^{10}$.  So maybe $10^{11} > 11^{10}$.  And it is.

A single example *is* a proof.  But...

Okay a *real* proof.

Let $f(x) = 10^x - x^{10}$.  $f(10) = 10^{10}-10^{10} = 0$.

$f'(x) = 10^x*\ln(x) - 10*x^9$.  $f'(10) = 10^{10}*\ln{10} - 10*10^9 = 10^{10}(\ln{10} - 1)$.

Well $10 > e$ so $\ln{10} > 1$ so $f'(10) > 0$.

So $f$ is increasing at $x = 10$.  So there exists an $x > 10$ where $f(x) > f(10)$.

And that's that, isn't it?

$\exists x > 10 > 2| 10^x - x^{10} > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way to prove the existence of something is to explicitly provide it.

We have: $11 > 2 \land 10^{11} = 100\,000\,000\,000 > 25\,937\,424\,601 = 11^{10}$

So how did I get to $11$? Well, obviously, for $x=10$, we have $10^x=x^{10}$, so something larger than $10$ should be a good candidate. I then tried $11$ and it worked.

And yes, showing that $11$ fulfils the condition is a perfectly valid proof for the existence of an $x$ that fulfils the condition.